# Python Sum of digits in a string function

Tags: python

My function needs to take in a sentence and return the sum of the numbers inside. Any advice?

```
def sumOfDigits(sentence):
    sumof=0
    for x in sentence:
        if sentence.isdigit(x)== True:
            sumof+=int(x)
    return sumof
```

Comment: `sumOf` is not the same as `sumof`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
if sentence.isdigit(x)== True:
```

to:

```
if x.isdigit():
```

examples:

```
 >>> "1".isdigit()
 True
 >>> "a".isdigit()
 False
```

your code should be like:

```
def sumOfDigits(sentence):
    sumof=0
    for x in sentence:
        if x.isdigit():
            sumof+=int(x)
    return sumof
```

Some pythonic ways:

Using List Comprehension:

```
>>> def sumof(sentence):
...     return sum(int(x) for x in sentence if x.isdigit())
... 
>>> sumof("hello123wor6ld")
12
```

Using Filter, map:

```
>>> def sumof(sentence):
...     return sum(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, sentence)))
... 
>>> sumof("hello123wor6ld")
12
```

Using Regular expression, extraction all digit:

```
>>> import re
>>> def sumof(sentence):
...     return sum(map(int, re.findall("\d",sentence)))
... 
>>> sumof("hello123wor6ld")
12
```

Comment: What else would I need to add so that it can return the sum?

Comment: if you have replace what i have told your code will work fine, you can check my other methods too

Comment: With list comprehension, would this go right below sumof+=int(x)

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask if x is a digit.

```
def sumOfDigits(sentence):
    sumof=0
    for x in sentence:
        if x.isdigit()== True:
            sumof+=int(x)
    return sumof
```