# Determining validity if sum divisible by 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Outline:

> Find out if id is acceptable. Acceptable parameters is the sum of the
> digits for each part of the id. If each sum is evenly divisible by 10
> then the function returns the string "Acceptable", otherwise it
> returns the string "Unacceptable".

## Example:

> `isValid('123-12-134')` → 'Unacceptable'
>
> `isValid('550-55-055')` → 'Acceptable'
>
> `isValid('123-55-055')` → 'Unacceptable'

I've tried converting the entire string into an int, but get some differing results in determining divisible by 10.

## My attempted code is:

```
def isValid(id) :
  id=id.replace('-','0')
  id=int(id)
  
  if id % 10==0:
    return "Valid"
  
  else:
    return "Invalid"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) Format your code correctly. (2) The assignment says "sum... for each part... ".

Comment: Do not use `id` as an identifier. It is the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well return boolean variables and just compare the output to determine what to print:

```
def summation(item):
  return sum([int(i) for i in item])

def isValid(id_) :
  id_part = id_.split('-')
  result = [summation(item) % 10 == 0 for item in id_part]
  return all(result)
```

1. Essentially this loops through all the characters in the split string and determines their sum - 3 sums per provided id.
2. Then we convert the summed list to a boolean list using your condition of `x%10 == 0`.
3. Finally we look at `all()` the elements of this boolean list to determine if it all `True` or contains a `False`.

If all are `True` then the return of `isValid(id_)` is `True` else it is `False`.

## Usage:

```
ids = ['123-12-134', '550-55-055', '123-55-055']
for id_ in ids:
  validity = isValid(id_)
  print("Acceptable") if validity else print("Unacceptable")
```

## Output:

```
Unacceptable
Acceptable
Unacceptable
```

Comment: isValid('4-3-3') return True, but shouldn't this be invalid (i.e. each part needs to be divisible by 10)?

Comment: Glad to help. Seems all the other answers also have this error.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
sentence = "123-123-123"
a = sum(int(x) for x in sentence if x.isdigit())
```

Hope this code can help you.

Found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442238/python-sum-of-digits-in-a-string-function)

Comment: The instruction is `sum of the digits for each part of the id`, not all digits.

Comment: The assignment says "sum... for each part... "!

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
sentence = "123-123-123"
a = sum(int(x) for x in sentence if x.isdigit())
return a % 10 == 0
```

Hope this code can help you.

Found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442238/python-sum-of-digits-in-a-string-function)

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires splitting the string into parts using hyphens as separators, which are tested to ensure that the sum of each part's characters is a multiple of 10. The test fails if any of the parts are not a multiple of ten, so each part must be greater than or equal to ten. If any part fails, the string fails, so, there is no need to continue testing if a failed part is found. Acceptable must be returned if the string passes, or Unacceptable if it fails.

This single function solution is easy to read:

```
def teststring(test):
    for part in test.split('-'):
        part_failed = int(part)<10
        if not part_failed:
            sum_chars = 0
            for char in part:
                sum_chars += int(char)
            part_failed = ((sum_chars % 10) != 0)
        if part_failed: break
    return 'Acceptable' if not part_failed else 'Unacceptable'
```

This solution uses list comprehension in two functions:

```
def testpart_comprehended(part):
    return ((int(part)>=10) and ((sum(int(char) for char in part) % 10) == 0))

def acceptable_comprehended(test):
    return 'Acceptable' if all(testpart_comprehended(part) for part in test.split("-")) else 'Unacceptable'
```

This solution uses list comprehension in one function:

```
def all_comprehended(test):
    return 'Acceptable' if all(((int(part)>=10) and ((sum(int(char) for char in part) % 10) == 0)) for part in test.split("-")) else 'Unacceptable'
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to short-circuit the 'Unacceptable'.

```
def isValid(ID):
    s = 0
    for x in ID:
        if x.isdigit():
            s += int(x)
        else:
            if s % 10 == 0:
                s = 0
            else:
                return 'Unacceptable'

    return 'Acceptable' if s%10 == 0 else 'Unacceptable'
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all too understandable.  Please use

```
isValid = lambda x: (any(sum(map(int, s)) % 10 for s in x.split('-'))
                     * 'un' + 'acceptable').title()
```

Unacceptable
for example

```
>>> isValid('123-123')
'Unacceptable'
>>> isValid('123-127')
'Unacceptable'
>>> isValid('127-127')
'Acceptable'
```